# iFrame a website using EclipseAndroid SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, iframe-app

I am trying to develop an android app. Could anyone tell me a bit in details that how to iFrame a website using Eclipse? I would highly appreciate if anyone can tell me

Comment: create an activity with a single webview. Call get a reference to your webview inside oncreate and use loadUrl to point to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "iFrame a website" you mean you want to load a web page inside your app. You should use WebView. See the Android documentation for [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I meant iFrame a website or display a page in the app. I think you are right about the WebView. I will go through it now. Thanks a lot!